# HTML: Trouble with images in a seperate folder to web page

Tags: html, image

I want to be able to use images in a separate folder for my web page, however when I run the page, the image fails to appear. Previously I had the image I wanted to use in the same place a the web page and that worked fine, however once I placed the image in a folder and tried to run the web page, the image no longer showed. I have checked to make sure I have made sure that I have spelt files and folder correctly that I have the correct path, I have also tried adding ../ to the front, but that didn't work. Many thanks for any help.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
    <title>title goes here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>This is a heading</h1>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <img src="/Art/Head_Drawings.jpg" alt="Heads_examples" width="104" height="142"></img>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Where is your html file, in comparison to Head_Drawings.jpg?

Comment: By the way, there is no </img> tag

Comment: Along with spelcheck, do file extension check as well. .jpg not equals .jpeg . Just to be sure!

Comment: Also, try the path without the initial slash.

Comment: both file are in This PC>Documents except the image Head_Drawings.jpg is in a folder called Art in the same place. However I managed to get it to work by removing the forward slash, many thanks

Answer (score -1):

1. You have the image tag wrong. It's one of those self-closing tags in HTML.

`<img src="" ... />` or `<img src="" ... >` is all you need for an image to show up.

2. if the image is a directory at the same level as your HTML page, you don't need the leading `/`.

Here is the correct way to add your image to the page:

`<img src="Art/Head_Drawings.jpg" alt="Heads_examples" width="104" height="142" />`

Comment: "You have the image tag wrong. It's one of those self-closing tags in HTML" — while wrong, an end tag for an img element is harmless and not the cause of the problem.

Comment: "if the image is a directory at the same level as your HTML page, you don't need the leading /." — The OP figured that out four years ago and said so in a comment. Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow. You can delete this answer to remove the possibility of blocking such clean up.